# Rebooting Windows host while VMWare server is running

Tags: windows-7, vmware

I have installed vmware server 2.0.2 on my windows 7 pc and installed ubuntu via vmware web access.

Now I am wondering if I need to log in to my virtual os (ubuntu) and shut it down before I restart or shut down my windows host? Or does vmware does it itself automatically?

Thanks
B

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I'd hazard a guess that the VMware is saving the state of your guest system when it gets the shut down signal. At least that is what any reasonable sane developer would make his system do.

Easy test - open the VM and open a texteditor. Type something. Close the VM interface and reboot. Open VM interface and check if the editor window is there.

Comment: I tried this and the virtual pc was shutdown. I am wondering if this is secure way to do it? I mean will it cause any problem on the guest os?

Comment: Any file is a security risk, but for general use this should not be a problem. It should not cause any problems on the guest, as the guest is not aware that it was saved and closed after you start it up again. This is a safe way of using the VM.

Comment: the VM may not be set to save states, it may merely send a signal to the host simulating pressing the power button, in which case the guest would shut down correctly, but the editor would not be active the next time it runs.

Comment: @Synetech, that would probably be a better move than saving the state of the guest, as saving usually takes more time than just shutting down. A fast exit strategy would be a wise move, to keep the user wait time down.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest running a more current version of VMware. You can get 3.51 or 4.0 ESXi server via a free download. Then you will need to install the VMware tools on the guest OS. Once that is done the guest OS shutdown will be handled properly and automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, just do a test.

Run the VM, boot the guest OS, then close the VM (Alt+F4 or reboot the host OS). Then run the VM again and see if the guest OS boots. If it does not, that is, if it just restores to where it was, then the state was saved and restored and you should be fine. If it *does* boot, then your VM is not set to save/restore states. In this case, you need to watch the boot to see if it shows any indication of a bad shutdown. (I’m not familiar with the ins and outs of Ubuntu, but I’m sure that it has some sort of notice or system/disk-check on the next boot after a bad shutdown.)

Also, make sure that the guest OS is set to handle power-down events (like pressing the power button on a physical system) because VMs generally shut down guest OSes by simulating that button being pressed, otherwise it ends up being “shut down” as it would if you just cut the power.